# How can I use HERE maps api to detect the object or nearest marker of the user's location showing the path with a line like the route api?

Tags: javascript, here-api

I have an application with **HERE maps api**. What I want to do is as follows:

When the user clicks the button, HERE maps API should detect the object or mark nearest to the user's location and show the path with a line from the user's current position to the nearest mark.

You know, like the line that the here maps API route API shows.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can:

1. Programmatically implement the logic of finding the nearest point (point B) relative to the user's location (point A)
2. To build the route between A and B points by HERE Routing API https://developer.here.com/api-explorer/maps-js/services/map-with-route-from-a-to-b

Comment: ppostnov, Now I need to take a route that leaves the user's current location and goes to the nearest destination. This is the relationship I intend to make but I can't.

Comment: Did you already getting the nearest point ? I mean you do you have a possibolity to receiving the nearest point's x,y ?

Comment: Yes i have ppostnov